# Is it possible for a Windows Phone application communicate with the Web service, if it is not in the foreground state?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Is it possible for a Windows Phone application to receive messages from a web service and respond to them when it is not in foreground? For example, during incoming call. Because if the web service does not receive a response from the client, the client will be disconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would drain the battery if a user wouldn't shutdown the app. Consider allowing the client to disconnect since mobile applications always disconnect arbitrarily because of signal.

you may run your app in the background if your app is a location tracking application. You may fail certification if you misuse this feature.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that you can send API request while running in the background.

There is a battery drain issue. You should monitor the battery yourself, if your app notice the battery falling below a certain percentage, you should discontinue making API calls. If you don't the system will do it for you. At least if you do it, you can notify the user.